# TFS "Copy Outputs to Drop Folder" parameter in build process template

Tags: tfs, build-process

I want do some job in my build process template only if parameter "Copy Outputs to Drop Folder" is set to true. Is there any variable that is associated with this parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to do it by checking `Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(BuildDetail.DropLocation)`.